# code.exe ignoring command-line arguments

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, visual-studio-code

I hope this is an easy fix, but I couldn't find any documentation or other posts on the matter.  I'm trying to write a script (`cmd` or `pwsh`) that will launch vscode with my preferences on a portable install.

When trying to execute vscode's `code.exe` with any arguments, it ignores them and just launches the program as if I had typed nothing else.  I'm [following this doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line) in my testing.  Using alias switches doesn't work, either.  The only argument that *does* seem to process is if I include a path.

```
code.exe --help
code.exe --version
```

---

Additionally, after launching `code.exe`, the console kind of hangs, then vscode status messages are sent to that console (even without use of the `--wait` switch).  If I close the console, vscode shuts down.  Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using **Code** via shell (`cmd` or `pwsh`), it does not use `Code.exe`, but the script/batch files located under `Bin` folder (`code.cmd`). These are the applications which really recognizes the command line switches.

This is not entirely clear in the [Command Line Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line) page, but looking closer at the [Note](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_launching-from-command-line) you will see that it does say the `Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin` folder.

Comment: Further clarification, I'm explicitly calling `Code.exe`.  When I tried calling that batch file, it just opened that `cli.js` file in the editor.

Comment: What happens if you call `code --version` (outside your script)?

Comment: I don't have code in my PATH (note, portable download).  It doesn't do anything unless I'm in the proper directory.  That said, it just launches VSCode, no console output.

Comment: VS Code does not have an _oficial portable download_, so you must check from your _provider_ where the startup `scritp/batch` is located. If I remember correctly, the `Code.exe` is just a renamed `Electron.exe`.

Comment: I don't believe that's accurate. After more testing, it does accept cli-args (was able to manually set extensions & user directory), but the status-oriented ones (`--help`/`--version`) aren't working.

Comment: Checkout this open issue (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/329)